# How to properly close a peerconnection

Tags: ios, webrtc

I have a voip app using webrtc. I recently redesigned a lot of the code to make the signaling a lot more consistent. The only big problem I have now is that when I close the peerconnection the app crashes on some internal opengl code. I use this code to close the connection:

```
[peerConnection removeStream:lms];
[peerConnection close];
peerConnection = nil;
```

The code I used previously deleted pretty much anything related to webrtc, but I found out that a lot of object can be reused and only have to be inited at the start of the app. What do I have to do to make sure the app doesn't crash everything I end a call?

- I'm using revision 6825
- I'm using xcode 5.1.1
- Testing on an iPad 4th generation, running iOS7

Edit:
I moved the above code to a background thread and it no longer crashes. But now, after a few calls, my log gets spammed with the following line (about 3 or 4 times per second):

```
Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
```

This is the last part of the log history when this happens:

```
2014-10-14 11:53:45.045 BeeldZorgApp[4912:3903] peerConnection iceConnectionChanged:(RTCICEConnectionState)2
2014-10-14 11:53:45.046 BeeldZorgApp[4912:3903] peerConnection iceConnectionChanged:(RTCICEConnectionState)3
2014-10-14 11:53:50.732 BeeldZorgApp[4912:3903] peerConnectionOnRenegotiationNeeded:(RTCPeerConnection *)<RTCPeerConnection: 0x157c9640>
2014-10-14 11:53:50.742 BeeldZorgApp[4912:3903] peerConnection iceConnectionChanged:(RTCICEConnectionState)6
2014-10-14 11:53:50.743 BeeldZorgApp[4912:3903] peerConnection signalingStateChanged:(RTCSignalingState)5
2014-10-14 11:53:59.955 BeeldZorgApp[4912:3903] peerConnectionOnRenegotiationNeeded:(RTCPeerConnection *)<RTCPeerConnection: 0x19a62e30>
2014-10-14 11:53:59.980 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.028 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.091 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.119 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.152 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.185 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.218 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.252 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.284 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.319 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.352 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.384 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.417 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.451 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.486 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.518 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
2014-10-14 11:54:00.552 BeeldZorgApp[4912:60b] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cdd
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out the RTCEAGLVideoViews need to be removed from their superview before navigating away from the view controller. I now use the following code to clean up:

```
//these are both RTCEAGLVideoViews
[remoteVideoView removeFromSuperview];
[localVideoView removeFromSuperview];
[peerConnection removeStream:lms];
[peerConnection close];
peerConnection = nil;
```

Comment: wish i could give you up 1000 times for your line 'I moved the above code to a background thread and it no longer crashes' .. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you set `peerConnection` as nil, you'll get an error about this in view controller when you try call someone again (in second time). 
I think it sets as nil of `peerConnection` value of **PeerConnectionFactory** static class. So when you call **peerConnectionWithConfiguration** method of the factory, you'll get nil value.
My suggestion is that the `close()` method is enough (with swift):

```
self.remoteVideoView.removeFromSuperview()
self.localVideoView.removeFromSuperview()
self.peerConnection.removeStream(self.mediaStream)
self.peerConnection.close()
```

PS: I'm using lastest version of webrtc library

Comment: You can't reuse the peerconnection object itself (the variable sure, but not the instance), you'll have to create a new one. So why keep the object in memory? Just calling close() might be enough to make it work, but it's not very clean.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm not right but I'm waiting that iOS removes all variable when I dismiss the view controller. Because they're variables and they depend on the instance. According to you, we have to set as nil all variables before removing instance.@Kevin

Comment: That depends on wether you use ARC or not, I don't in my webrtc implementation so I clear everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

On my code I did something like this. I was facing an issue where the microphone yellow dot was visible even after ending the call. This code fixed everything:

```
if let capturer = self.videoCapturer as? RTCCameraVideoCapturer{
        capturer.stopCapture()
    }
    
    self.screenCapturer = nil
    
    if(self.peerConnection != nil) {
        for mStream in self.peerConnection!.localStreams {
            peerConnection?.remove(mStream)
        }
    }
    
    for participant in remoteParticipants {
        participant.peerConnection?.close()
    }
    
    self.peerConnection?.close()
    self.webSocketListener?.endConnection()
    
    self.delegate = nil
    self.remoteParticipants.removeAll()
    self.webSocket = nil
    localVideoTrack = nil
    remoteVideoTracks.removeAll()
    localDataChannel = nil
    remoteDataChannel = nil
    self.peerConnection = nil
}
```